# Use of “ less” as adverb in sentence

Tags: adverbs

Can i use “ less “ as adverb in sentence like :

> I earned $500 less in this month.

As far as i understand , i need to add “ than... “ after “ less” to use it as adverb .

Comment: Normally we'd expect a ***than-** clause* after ***less***. But this is a matter of "logic" *(less than **what?**)* rather than a syntactic rule. In your example, it's probably contextually obvious you mean *less than **usual*** (of course, you might mean *less than **someone else earned*** or something else, but doubtless in that case the context would make *that* intended sense clear).

Answer (score 4):

Yes I think the sentance is correct, however I would remove "in"

> I earned $500 less this month.

To give you an exemple you could also say:

> I earned $500 less this month than in January.

Answer (score 2):

I'd lose the *in*, but that's not directly related to your question.

If you use *more* or *less* then there has to be something you're comparing things *to*. That's where the *than* comes in. However, where that comparator is obvious from context or just from the sentence itself, it can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

> *I earned $500 less this month (than I did last month).*

I don't take "less" to be an adverb here but a comparative determinative functioning as a modifier in the fused determiner-head noun phrase "$500 less".

It's the kind of comparative construction where one would expect some obligatory reduction in the comparative clause. But here, the reduction has been taken one step further and the entire comparative element has been omitted, but understood to be the bracketed phrase.